# Notificación Local no funciona con Android 11

Tags: android, android-studio, xamarin, android-intent, push-notification

Tengo un método de C# que funciona sin problemas con mi dispositivo de pruebas con `Android 6`, pero cuando lo pruebo en mi dispositivo con `Android 11` no logro que me cree la notificación.

Lo que el método debe hacer es recibir el string del titulo y string del mensaje para luego generar una tarjeta de notificación en el panel de notificaciones del dispositivo.

Pero es exactamente el mismo código, solo cambie el dispositivo, no entiendo que sucede y no me genera ningun tipo de error. Simplemente no lo imprime. No se si sera debido a algun permiso especial en Android 11.

Metodo:

```
public int CrearNotificacionLocal(string pTitle, string pBody)
        {
            try
            { //Configuracion general de notificacion...

                if (!channelInitialized)
                {
                    CreateNotificationChannelO();
                }

                messageId++;

                //Intent intent = new Intent(AndroidApp.Context, typeof(MainActivity));
                Intent intent = new Intent(AndroidApp.Context, typeof(cNotificaciones));
                intent.PutExtra(TitleKey, pTitle);
                intent.PutExtra(MessageKey, pBody);
                intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(AndroidApp.Context, pendingIntentId, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(AndroidApp.Context, channelId)
                    .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .SetContentTitle(pTitle)
                    .SetContentText(pBody)
                    .SetAutoCancel(true)
                    //.SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(AndroidApp.Context.Resources, Resource.Mipmap.Icono3))
                    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Mipmap.Icono3)
                    .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.Sound | (int)NotificationDefaults.Vibrate);

                var notification = builder.Build();
                manager.Notify(messageId, notification);

                //return messageId;

            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                //
            }

            return messageId;
        }
```

**Edit:** Funcion que crea el canal (categoria) de notificaciones:

```
void CreateNotificationChannelO()
        {
            try
            {
                manager = (NotificationManager)AndroidApp.Context.GetSystemService(AndroidApp.NotificationService);

                if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
                {
                    var channelNameJava = new Java.Lang.String(channelName);
                    var channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelNameJava, NotificationImportance.Default)
                    {
                        Description = channelDescription
                    };
                    manager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
                }

                channelInitialized = true;

            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                
            }
        }
```

Comment: Pero es que son distintas versiones de android, se requieren otras cosas u otros permisos...

Comment: Falta mas información a tu pregunta, imprime si sucede un error en el catch. es muy importante imprimir los errores. Agrega que es CreateNotificationChannelO()? , que determina el valor de channelInitialized ?

Comment: Eso no es de mucha ayuda, pero gracias @FranqoBalsamo

Comment: Tienes razon @Jorgesys, olvide agregar el metodo de CreateNotificationChannelO(). Lo acabo de agregar.    No agregue error del catch porque no da ningun error, simplemente no imprime la notificacion, pero puedo brindarles lo que necesiten ya que he revisado hasta donde mi conocimiento me lo permite pero no descifro que podria ser. Gracias.